# Using jquery method from external library after enqueing

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Hi Stackoverflow community

I am new to developing with WordPress and have a question.

I have a plugin with the jellyfish-widget.php file. It renders a counter onto your website. Unfortunately the plugin is not responsive. To make it responsive I would like to call a method inside the jellyfish.js file which renders the counter into the DOM. Unfortunately the method I would like to call relies on an external jquery library which I would like to import.

Inside the jellyfish-widget.php file I therefore registered and enqueued (and add_action) a jquery script called 'modernizr.js'. Inside my jellyfish.js script I now want to call a method from this enqued jquery library called 'modernizr'.

Here my question - to successfully call the method which is defined in modernizer.js from within my jellyfish.js, does it suffice to registered and enqueued modernizer.js (with the correct file path of course)?

It seems strange that I would not be require to ensure that my js file knows where the method comes from. Or would I be required to do something special to call my method from this external library.

Comment: I would recommend not using any JS/jQuery to make this widget responsive. It can be achieved using pure CSS. Using JS to detect screen size is always a headache

Comment: Absolutely agree. The trouble is that the size of the counter - aka, the size of its digits are determined through a user setting in word press. This means that the user can tell the plugin how large they would like the counter to be. That said, the jellyfish.js file is where the counter is rendered based on the user's input. As such the css file doesn't contain the height and width of the the counter itself, meaning that I wouldn't have anything to run a media query on. Hence this approach.